# Update specific column with the value of single column from another table

Tags: sql

I want to update the specific column with value of a single column from another table using sql query.

The specific column I want to update is in the `WorkingTime` table. Like for example I want to update its value by 1 depending on its `IDNo` and `Date` from TABLE 2

`WorkingTime` table:

```
 IDNo   | PeriodDate | SPLP | NVLP | NBLP | PLP | BLP | MLP | SLP | VLP | NSLP |
18-031  |06/11/2017  |  0   |  0   |  0   |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0   |
18-032  |06/12/2017  |  0   |  0   |  0   |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0   |
18-033  |06/13/2017  |  0   |  0   |  0   |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0   |
```

And the name of the column I want to update in `WorkingTime` is in the `LeaveDetails`. The column with the name `LeaveType`.

`LeaveDetails`:

```
Contro  | IDNo   | LeaveType| DateFrom | DateTo   | NoOfDays |
000041  |18-031  |  SPLP    |06/11/2019|06/11/2019|  1       |
000042  |18-032  |  NVLP    |06/12/2019|06/12/2019|  1       |
000043  |18-033  |  PLP     |06/13/2019|06/13/2019|  1       |
```

And my expected result after the query is this

Expected result:

```
 IDNo   | PeriodDate | SPLP | NVLP | NBLP | PLP | BLP | MLP | SLP | VLP | NSLP |
18-031  |06/11/2017  |  1   |  0   |  0   |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0   |
18-032  |06/12/2017  |  0   |  1   |  0   |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0   |
18-018  |06/13/2017  |  0   |  0   |  0   |  1  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0   |
```

Can anyone please help me with the query i will use to make this happen. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Most people here want sample table data and expected result as formatted text, not as images (or links to images.)

Comment: Your question is not clear. You say you want to update a value in the first table by 1, and you also want to update the LeaveType column in the second table. Why don't you provide an example of what you want to do? Like "I want to update column xxx in table 1, if column yyy in table 2 equals 5" or something like that. If you pose the question clearly you will get an answer you can use.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using

Comment: Sorry guys. im new with this. i try to edit my post. hope to make it all clear to you,

Answer (score 1):

I'm unclear which tables/columns you are trying to update but you can update a column value in one table using the column value of a different table by using a sub query, for example:

```
UPDATE TABLE_1
SET LEAVETYPE = 
(SELECT NEW_COLUMN FROM TABLE_2 WHERE PRIMARY_KEY = 'Something')
WHERE PRIMARY_KEY = 'Something'
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to Use temp table. first take your data in temp table then update main table by using temp table data. 
Or using join the table
update u
set u.assid = s.assid
from ud u
    inner join sale s on
        u.id = s.udid

Answer (score 0):

One method is a series of `case` expressions and subqueries:

```
update table1
    set splp = (case when exists (select 1
                                  from table2 t2
                                  where t2.idno = table1.idno and
                                        t2.perioddate = t1.perioddate and
                                        t2.leavetype = 'SPLP'
                                 )
                     then 1 else table1.splp
                end),
        splp = (case when exists (select 1
                                  from table2 t2
                                  where t2.idno = table1.idno and
                                        t2.perioddate = t1.perioddate and
                                        t2.leavetype = 'NVLP'
                                 )
                     then 1 else table1.nvlp
                end),
     . . .;
```

Depending on the database, there are other approach as well, but the above should work in any database.

Comment: Thank you so much @Gordon Linoff this works with me